# redux-form@8.3.7 requires a peer of react@^16.4.2 but none is installed

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have got a problem when I tried to install redux form:

**redux-form@8.3.7 requires a peer of react@^16.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.**

according to my package.json, I already installed React 17.0.1, so why this warning is still there? Although my app works but the redux form does not work correctly.I am thinking if the lack of peer is where the issue comes from.

I hope someone could help me, thanks!

Comment: the caret(^) in react@^16.4.2 means `Compatible with version, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version`

so the version of redux-form that you're trying to install is not compatible with react 17

Comment: after I installed the React@16.4.2, other warnings come up...react-dom and react redux that i use require different versions of react...does it mean that i cannot make them work together because of the version issue..

Comment: unfortunately, you might have to downgrade those as well in order for redux-form to work properly. you could also raise this issue with redux-form github and see when they're planning to support this.